# C++ move constructor for a class with string member

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I've wrote a class with following code:

```
class Test {
public:
...
    Test( const Test &&that ) : i(that.i), s(std::move(that.s)) {
        cout << "move contructor." << endl;
    }
...
private:
    int i;
    std::string s;
};
```

if I disassemble the generated code I see:

```
        .type   Test::Test(Test const&&), @function
Test::Test(Test const&&):
...
       call    std::remove_reference<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>::type&& std::move<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
        movq    %rax, %rsi
        movq    %rbx, %rdi
.LEHB3:
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)@PLT
```

it surprises me the call to `basic_string<...>::basic_string( basic_string<...> const&)` because I expected a call to the move constructor of the basic_string `basic_string<...>::basic_string( basic_string<...> &&)`.

I'm implementing in a incorrect way the move constructor ?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Is this the debug or the release variant of the code?

Comment: @HajoKirchhoff: g++ 9.3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rvalue references to const types aren't very useful. They say that code can steal from the object, but must do so without changing its value?

Since `std::string` doesn't have a `string(const string&&)` move constructor, overload resolution can only use the `string(const string&)` copy constructor.

A normal move constructor doesn't use the `const`:

```
Test( Test &&that ) : i(that.i), s(std::move(that.s)) {
    std::cout << "move constructor." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: My mistake, thanks. Removed const and the assembler is now the expected one. Note: it could be nice a move that restricts his parameter to something non-const.